# Modeling determinants of secondary sales of a good

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, causality

I have a dataset with transactions made on around 10,000 items in the past year. Part of the items in the dataset were bought only once (1 transaction), and others were resold (>1 transaction). I want to determine what influences that an item is resold more (e.g., initial price, popularity, visual properties) but don't know where to start - which methods could I use, and how would I express the resales in my data, because for now I can see the resales by the no. of rows that repeat themselves for a given item (one row-one transaction)? I was thinking of using multiple regression and making my dependent variable the number of times an item was resold (one row-one item-no. of times it was sold), but does that make sense?

Does anyone have any tips, suggestions? I would especially appreciate any book suggestions or similar papers, as I feel I don't even know which options I have or how to go about them! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try Poisson regression already?  This was my first thought, because you are working with count data

Comment: @BenA I haven't, thank you for the suggestion. Would my approach with resale counts then be correct?

Comment: You'd want to model $y\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, where $y$ is 1 less than the resale count. This is because a Poisson r.v. can be any non-negative integer

Comment: @BenA Do you have any literature recommendations which could help me in applying this? I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge right off the bat to apply this :)

Comment: I'd recommend fitting one of these models in R. You could try reading https://katrienantonio.github.io/intro-R-book/glms.html  for an example or two, or more generally on Generalized Linear Models for the theory. Unfortunately I suspect you will need to understand a little theory to be able to interpret the model. If you want to use python instead of R, then there is https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html

Comment: @BenA Thanks a lot!